# Is a different sitemap per language OK? How do I tell Google about them?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml

The website is very, very large and I have created:

- *sitemap_fr.xml*
- *sitemap_en.xml*
- *sitemap_es.xml*

Is this solution OK? If so, do I have to insert a tag to inform Google about the different sitemaps?  I no longer just have *sitemap.xml* which it could find automatically.

I am using hreflang tags already:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://website.net/fr" >
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://website.net/en" >
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://website.net/es" >
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have multiple sitemaps per website, and this is a great example of when that makes sense.

You should make sure you have a [Sitemap Index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712) listing each of your sitemaps. It will probably look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://website.net/sitemap_fr.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2004-10-01</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://website.net/sitemap_en.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://website.net/sitemap_es.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Remember to link that index in your robots.txt file, like:

```
Sitemap: http://website.net/sitemapindex.xml
```

<sub>There's also the option to [indicate alternate language pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865) within your sitemap itself. It's slightly more complicated to set up and doesn't inherently answer the original question about the user's suggested setup.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Loft's suggestion of a sitemap index file is perfectly acceptable.  I agree with him that multiple sitemaps per site is OK and your use case for it is a good one.

There are two other ways to let Google know about multiple sitemaps that work just as well:

### Submit all the sitemaps to Google Webmaster Tools

You can submit a sitemap, no matter what it is named, via Google Webmaster Tools.   [Google's help documentation explains how](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en).

Once a sitemap is submitted in GWT, Google also shows you additional information about it such as the number of URLs from it which made it into Google's index.

### List them all in robots.txt

Sitemaps can be listed in [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).   The syntax is:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_fr.xml
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_en.xml
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_es.xml
```

Comment: This works well for Google, but doesn't follow the same spec for other search engines. Using a Sitemap Index will tell all search engines about your structure.

Comment: @AndrewLott listing them all in the sitemap directly should work for all search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Tag **hreflang** should be use in deeper level when structure looks like below

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_fr.xml
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_en.xml
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_es.xml
```

Or maybe for example sitemap_fr.xml has only FR content without  hreflang related to other languages

Comment: It was probably just an example and he probably uses the hreflang for all the pages.